# How to place a chart not from the beginning of the X axis

Tags: highcharts

I tried to place the line diagram not from the beginning of the axis. And an indication of the specific position by date. The chart is displayed, but very strange. It does not scale.

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    min: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    max: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1),
    type: 'datetime',
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 1),
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
    startOnTick: false


  },

  series: [{
    name: 'test',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 5),
    offset: 100,
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
    pointInterval: 3600 * 1000

  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css">

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/js/highstock.js"></script>

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
```

How to fix it?

```
[JS Fiddle][1]


 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/6orqa0ym/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highstock charts have enabled `ordinal` options for `xAxis` by default, which causes inconvenience in your case. You can easily disable that option:

```
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        ordinal: false
    },
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x8f05ys3/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal